# Unity 2D/3D c# Solid

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно ли в юнити использовать принципы solid?Просто ниразу не видел что бы кто либо при написании игры их использовал,поэтому и сложился вопрос,так же он сложился из за например принципа единой ответственности допустим есть враг и на нем должно будет висеть множество скриптов отвечающих за атаку,за передвижение,поворот и т.д,из за этого можно будет забыть добавить какой либо компонент и получается довольно неудобно.

Answer (score 6):

> допустим есть враг и на нем должно будет висеть множество скриптов отвечающих за атаку,за передвижение,поворот и т.д,из за этого можно будет забыть добавить какой либо компонент и получается довольно неудобно.

Если повесить такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Walker))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Weapon))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(WeaponMelee))]
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{ }
```

то юнити проследит автоматом что бы на обьекте с этим скриптом были так же `Rigidbody`, `Walker`, `Weapon`, `WeaponMelee` скрипты. И ты гарантированно ничего не забудешь.

Comment: А если врагу нужно сделать ренж атаку))) через базовый класс атаки допустим Attack(){ GetComponent<Attack>().Attack() } в таком случае он ищет на объекте базовый компонент например с реализацией в ренж атаку,а у другого объекта будет милли атака тогда получается что изначальные компоненты не помогут)

Comment: Такое можно реализовать через интерфейсы или через переопределения методов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299602/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%A8%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9E/

Comment: @citrus на этом сервисе не очень любят теоретические вопросы без привязки к реальной ситуации. Потому что отвечаешь на вопрос, а за ним следует "А если", отвечаешь и на это, а за ним следует следующее "А если" и так далее. Поэтому если у тебя есть некая конкретная ситуация - спрашивай помощи. Если это чисто теоретический интерес - не трать время здешних завсегдаев, лучше почитай книгу по этой тематике. Она ответит на множество практических и теоретических вопросов и при этом не будешь тратить попусту время других специалистов.

Comment: Изначально вопрос был о том как проследить за тем что на обьект навешены все необходимые компоненты. Я на этот вопрос ответил четко, однозначно и коротко.

Answer (score 0):

Я также изучаю SOLID и Unity, поэтому для вас есть картинка которая обьясняет половину принципов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Если что ссылка на книгу
http://www.a0601.narod.ru/UnityInActon-RUS.pdf